# How to change the monaco editor's locale?

Tags: vue.js, locale, monaco-editor

I want to know how to change editor's locale?

eg: change en-us to zh-cn

This is for monaco-editor@0.17.1，vue@2.6.10

Answer (score 0):

安装monaco-editor-locales-plugin

```
npm instal -D monaco-editor-locales-plugin
```

weback配置

```
   //引入插件
const MonacoLocalesPlugin = require('monaco-editor-locales-plugin');  


new MonacoLocalesPlugin({  
        //设置支持的语言
        languages: ["es","zh-cn"],
        //默认语言
        defaultLanguage: "zh-cn",
        //打印不匹配的文本
        logUnmatched: false,
        //自定义文本翻译
        mapLanguages: {"zh-cn": {"Peek References": "查找引用", "Go to Symbol...": "跳到变量位置", "Command Palette": "命令面板"}}
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this plan, but it didn't take effect for me.